# Lubuntu Laptop - Closing lid, no display after opening (forced reboot required)

Tags: lubuntu, suspend, laptop, 32-bit

I see a number of ideas and sollutions out there, though in this case I'm more worried about making things worse than improving them.

Desired System:

Laptop Lid = Closed

> Suspend System

Laptop Lid = Open

> Start System & Require Password.

What's actually Happening:

Laptop Lid = Closed

> System Suspends/Shuts down

Laptop Lid = Open

> Power is back on, screen is powered, but no displayed image.

There are power settings and I've flipped those around with no apparent changes, so a crayon eaters guide how to proceed would be greatly appreciated! As always, just tell me what to do!

This is a [Compaq Presario M2000](https://support.hp.com/us-en/products/identify?q=Presario%20M2000&filter=-1&origin=pdp), Running Lubuntu - Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

THank you thank you thank you!

EDIT: Unable to see comments while editing this - so.... forgive the clunky responses (Why isn't 'add comment' the preferred way to respond to a question?)

K7AAY - p/n : EC214UA#ABA s/n: CNF5332R2Y

On the same sticker:
Service tag M2105US

Hope that helps!

EDIT2:

guiverc - I assume it's 'suspended'.

There is no display, so there's not response from any key combination I'm aware of (ex. Ctrl alt F4). Because there's no display I can't see if linux is still running...a blank screen is ....a blank screen.

When suspending via terminal (sudo systemctl suspend) The computer turns off (All fans stop) display is unpowered. Upon any key hit the computer farms start up again, the display turns on, and the log in is prompted (so that's functioning as intended...I believe)

I'm not familiar with HWE - and can't quite follow what's being request in the remainder of the comment. Would you like me to run a command: uname -r?

Thanks for all of your input

Comment: You mention when you close lid, the system suspends/shutsdown. Suspend is a different action to shutdown; doesn't it only suspend.  If it was shutdown, it'd be a new boot when you re-opened it. When you do re-open lid, but have no displayed image - does switching to text-terminal (ctrl+alt+F4 for example) still work?  is linux still running (ie. sysrq keys still work) ?    Also if you use command to suspend your system (eg. `sudo systemctl suspend`) do you have the same black/black screen on wake?   Are you using HWE? or not?  (what media installed system? or `uname -r` gives what result?)

Comment: 39 different models of laptops are found when I go to the HP/Compaq support site and search on 'Presario M2000'. Please flip it over, find the serial number sticker, and copy the model number from that same sticker, then click [edit] here and put that true model number into your question. Please don't use Add Comment, because its space is limited; use [edit] instead.